# how to set label position respecting the tabcontrol size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, position

I'm setting an text in the label that is variable, so I need set dynamically the position it.

For example:

text: `baa`

in form:

```
------------------
|             baa|
|                |
|                |
-----------------
```

text: `baaaaaaaa`

in form:

```
------------------
|       baaaaaaaa|
|                |
|                |
-----------------
```

ever in corner. how I do this? Thanks stackoverflow!

Comment: Rolled back.  Don't invalidate correct and complete answers by changing the question.  Ask another one.

Comment: ow, sorry! I'II do other question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it's [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) property to Top and Right.

```
label.Dock = DockStyle.Top | DockStyle.Right;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set `Auto Size` property of label to `False` and `TextAlign` Property
to `MiddleRight`
```